# Spark: avoid task restart when writing

Tags: csv, apache-spark, parquet

I have a Spark application that reads CSVs and writes Parquet files.

In some cases (too little allocated memory, lost executor), the Parquet tasks may fail and retry; I noticed in this case there are duplicated records, i.e. some CSVs were written to Parquet files many times as it retries.

What is the state of the art to avoid such duplicates? I already use `--conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1` but this works only for jobs, not tasks. Should the application fail if one stage fail, or is there any way to rollback?

Answer (score 3):

Spark uses `FileOutputCommitter` to manage staging output files and final output files.

The behavior of `FileOutputCommitter` has direct impact on the performance of jobs that write data. It has two methods, `commitTask` and `commitJob`.

Apache Spark 2.0 and higher versions use Apache Hadoop 2, which uses the value of `mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version` to control how commitTask and commitJob work.

Currently Spark ships with two default Hadoop commit algorithms — version 1 & version 2.

In **version 1**, commitTask moves data generated by a task from the task temporary directory to job temporary directory and when all tasks complete, commitJob moves data to from job temporary directory the final destination. This ensures the **Transactional writes at job level**.

In **version 2**, commitTask will move data generated by a task directly to the final destination and commitJob is basically a no-op. This ensures the **Transactional writes at Task level**. You may see duplicates, if the job is re-submitted.

In your case, set the `dataframe.write.option("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "1")` to ensure the Transactional writes at job level.

Reference: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/31/transactional-writes-cloud-storage.html